# IDEA - Is there any way to make combined(merged) action shortcuts?

Tags: intellij-idea

For example, `alt + cmd + v` is shortcut for behavior `split vertically`, and `alt + cmd + b` is shortcut for `go to implementation`. Question is how do I merge these two actions `split vertically` and `go to implementation` into only one shortcut(say `cmd + i`)?

Comment: Like a [macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do what you need by following these steps;

- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>(find in action) + type `start macro recording`
- enter your commands consecutively (shortcuts). It will start recording every shortcut/keystrokes.
- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + type `stop macro recording`
- enter a name for your macro (`testmacro`)
- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + type `edit macros` and select your recently created macro (`testmacro`)
- The list should be as following;

  - `Action: SplitVertically`
  - `Action: GotoDeclaration`
- update your macro by pressing `ok`
- select or put your cursor on the variable/method/class that you want to go to the declaration and hit - <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + type `testmacro` and <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Alternatively, it could be better to assign a shortcut to `Play saved macros` and then instead of typing a lot, you can select your macro from the list after hitting the shortcut of `play saved macros`.

Here are the screenshots of the process

[image: edit macro]

[image: play macro shortcut]

[image: play macro popup]